# Experimentally determined probability has an “error

Tags: probability, error-analysis, statistics

Feynman , in the paragraph [6-3](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_06.html) of the first Volume of this lectures, writes that an “experimentally determined” probability has an “error,” and writes ( *We have only 2 events*)

$$P(H)=\frac{N_{H}}{N}(+-)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{N}}.$$

Is this correction error only used in the case that $\frac{N_{H}}{N}$ is 0.5 ? If, yes what correction error should i use if the 2 events have unbalanced probabilities?

Comment: Feynman's crucial (random walk) context is missing in your Q. Worse, you omit this from just after: "There is an implication in such an expression that there is a “true” or “correct” probability which could be computed if we knew enough, and that the observation may be in “error” due to a fluctuation. There is, however, no way to make such thinking logically consistent. It is probably better to realize that the probability concept is in a sense subjective, that it is always based on uncertain knowledge, and that its quantitative evaluation is subject to change as we obtain more information."

Comment: That equation seems to be (6.14) in your link.  Your description above suggests that Feynman is encouraging such equations, but from the reading I get a different impression: He says an experimentalist might write that (it is not a true equation and can be ignored if you like). It is simply assuming the error is contained within a standard deviation (the standard deviation changes if $P[H]\neq 1/2$).